# Add timestamp to files

Tags: timestamp

[image: Terminal output]I am using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS. I would like to add a timestamp to some wav files so they can be uploaded to a web site. I would like the first file to be Garden2021-05-02_04-10-00.wav and the following files to increase by 30 seconds for each file.
How can I best do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's generally used with substitutions of the form `s/pattern/replacement/`, the perl-based `rename` command can actually accept any valid perl expressions. So for example (borrowing the initialization from [pLumo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339547/178692)) you could do:

```
rename -n -- '
  BEGIN{use Time::Piece; our $ts = Time::Piece->new(shift)}
  $_ = our $ts->strftime("Garden%F_%H-%M-%S.wav");
  $ts += 30
' "$(date -d 2021-05-02T04:10:00 +%s)" *.wav
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy with the suggested renamings.

Note that the files will be stamped in the order that `*` expands in your locale. If you want another order, then IMHO the simplest way is to switch to the Z-shell (`zsh`) where you can use *glob qualifiers* to specify the sort order. For example `*.wav(n)` or `*.wav(.non)` to sort plain files **n**umerically by **n**ame increasing:

```
% ls *.wav
1.wav  10.wav  11.wav  12.wav  2.wav  3.wav  4.wav  5.wav  6.wav  7.wav  8.wav  9.wav

% rename -n -- '
  BEGIN{use Time::Piece; our $ts = Time::Piece->new(shift)}
  $_ = our $ts->strftime("Garden%F_%H-%M-%S.wav");
  $ts += 30
' "$(date -d 2021-05-02T04:10:00 +%s)" *.wav(.non)
rename(1.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-10-00.wav)
rename(2.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-10-30.wav)
rename(3.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-11-00.wav)
rename(4.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-11-30.wav)
rename(5.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-12-00.wav)
rename(6.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-12-30.wav)
rename(7.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-13-00.wav)
rename(8.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-13-30.wav)
rename(9.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-14-00.wav)
rename(10.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-14-30.wav)
rename(11.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-15-00.wav)
rename(12.wav, Garden2021-05-02_04-15-30.wav)
```

If you can't use `zsh`, then you can do the same in other shells using an external `sort` together with `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.wav | sort -zn | xargs -0 rename -n -- '
  BEGIN{use Time::Piece; our $ts = Time::Piece->new(shift)}
  $_ = our $ts->strftime("Garden%F_%H-%M-%S.wav");
  $ts += 30
' "$(date -d 2021-05-02T04:10:00 +%s)"
```

Comment: Thanks Plumo and Steeldriver it works, but not sure if the files are in the correct order. Just noticed the original file numbers jump from 9 to 100 in terminal display. Is that to do with "Note that the files will be stamped in the order that * expands in your locale"? How do I correct that please?

Comment: @Marty it depends - please edit your question to make it clear how the order should be determined

Comment: Sorry Steeldriver, what I need is for the files to renew their names starting from the original file number 1.wav consecutively.

Comment: @Marty please see updated answer - note that the use of `zsh` with glob qualifiers would apply just as well to the loop in @pLumo's answer

Comment: Thanks again guys this gives exactly the result I need.

Answer (score 2):

Start with changing the date to a format that you can easily increase by 30 seconds, e.g. Unix timestamp:

```
timestamp=$(date -d 2021-05-02T04:10:00 +%s) # --> 1619921400
```

then you can increase the timestamp like this:

```
timestamp=$((timestamp+30))
```

To get your preferred filename, use `date`:

```
date -d @$timestamp "+Garden%F_%H-%M-%S.wav"
```

---

Now loop your files and combine the commands:

```
timestamp=$(date -d 2021-05-02T04:10:00 +%s)
for f in *.wav; do
    echo mv "$f" "$(date -d @$timestamp "+Garden%F_%H-%M-%S.wav")"
    timestamp=$((timestamp+30))
done
```

Once you're happy with the output, remove the `echo`.

Comment: The output looks fine. how do I remove the echo?

Comment: Just remove the `echo` in front of `mv` in the script so that it reads `mv ...` instead of `echo mv ...`